# How do I kill a process once I've successfully identified the PID in a script?

Tags: bash, kill, ps

I have a bash script that needs to kill a specific PID that can be obtained by:

```
ps -A | grep -m1 apcagent | awk '{print $1}'
```

The above code identifies the PID of apcagent... and now I want to kill it within my bash script. Suggestions? Ideas?

Comment: Do you want to send a `SIGKILL` or a `SIGINT` signal to the process?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, Benjamin W. for the link. You're right, that question answered mine:

`kill $(ps -A | grep -m1 apcagent | awk '{print $1}')`

Comment: Also see `pidof`. You can do a `kill $(pidof processname)`

Answer (score -1):

It should be as easy as:

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Did you look at man kill?

Comment: Don't use `-9` in everyday usage, as the process being killed doesn't get a chance to clean up after itself. `kill <pid>` should be sufficient for a well-behaved program.

Comment: Agreed, @chepner